# How apply Entity Framework Migration on production Server

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am working with Entity Framework code first.
I have managed to work with migrations, but i need to type commands in the Package Manager Console.
(for example Update-Database command).
It works fine, but it works on my developpemnt computer.

Now, imagine i have a lot of production server. Some of those servers are still in database version 1, others in version 3 and the lastest version is 5.
Is it possible to run the equivalent of Update-Database Command from C# Code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,you can do that.You have to change your `web.config` file's `connection string` according to your `production server` and then run :

```
PM> Update-Database
```

**Update :** to generate scripts.

```
PM > Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration: $InitialDatabase -TargetMigration: 
AddPostAbstract
```

You can refer this for more info : [**Getting a SQL Script**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx#script)

Comment: Is there a way to do this for example for an administrator which do not have visual studio ? I want to write a program or an hidden page or menu that will check the database version and do the stuff to update the structure...

Comment: then you have to generate the `migration scripts`.by using that script `DBA` can run those against the relevant db **without** `VS`.

Comment: Thanks but i do not understand how you generate those migration scripts ?

Answer (score 1):

DbUp is one other open source tool which is effective and provides robust features to perform production DB upgrade in EF Code first approach.

[Here](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/net-framework/deploying-an-entity-framework-database-into-production/) is an informative article comparing the Dbup open source tool vs EF migration feature.